# How to toggle div from display none to visible

Tags: jquery, css

I have a sub-navigation (`.nav-sub-wrapper`) that currently loads hidden and should only display visible when triggered on mobile/tablet devices. I have set the div with `display:none`, but then can't toggle it to visible or `display:block` when on mobile/tablet devices. I have also set the div to load hidden with jQuery, but again can't get the div to toggle visible on mobile/tablet devices.

```
if($(window).width() == '768'){
  $(".nav-sub-wrapper").hide();

  $(".hamburger").on('click', function(){
    $(".nav-sub-wrapper").toggle();
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap for your framework?

Comment: You could try to add a class that makes it visible...

Comment: I have tried using both `.hidden-md-down` and toggling a class for the div that just toggles `display:block`, but that isn't working either.

Comment: wouldn't a media query be better?

Comment: @RobA - I have a media query that hides the div on mobile and tablet, but need to be able to toggle the div visible on mobile and tablet. I tried toggling a class on the div to set it to `display:block`, but that didn't work.

Comment: Is your code inside the `$(document).ready()` function?

Comment: @Barmar - yes, the equivalent of it: `(function(){
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){`. This is a mixture of legacy code and new code.

Comment: I can't suggest @RobA's suggestion enough.  It's so much easier to change a CSS property using actual CSS than it is to rely on JS being enabled / working.

Comment: is your hamburger visable only on mobile / tablet

Comment: @RobA - Yes, it's only supposed to be visible on mobile/tablet.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you use == in your test, did you try to put <= instead. Then you indicate 768 as a string and not a number, try to change that. Also if you test your website on the desktop browser, maybe you could try to put code into a .resize(), like so :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
      .nav-sub-wrapper {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: blue;
      }

      .hamburger {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        background-color: red;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav-sub-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="hamburger"></div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>

      function navHidden() {
        if($(window).width() <= 768){
        $(".nav-sub-wrapper").hide();
        $(".hamburger").on('click', function(){
        $(".nav-sub-wrapper").toggle();
        });
       }else{
        $(".nav-sub-wrapper").show();
       }
      }

      $( window ).resize(function() {
       navHidden();
      });

      $( document ).ready(function(){
        navHidden();
      });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I also added an else condition so the .nav-sub-wrapper displays back over 768px wide. You can try this in your navigator and tell me if it matches what you expected ;-)

Comment: This is having no effect. The div is still displaying when resizing the window at or below 768px.

Comment: I'm able to get it to mostly work in console, but having a little trouble merging it with my code, without getting everything locked up in the nav hidden function. I've edited my question with all the code for that breakpoint, without your update. Can you provide a sample of your solution mixed in?

Comment: Seems @Lou has already answered your question.  Updating an answer to include your sprawling codebase will make this question useless for future visitors.  If you need further help with adding this to your production code, I'd suggest asking another question, or maybe hiring him to do this work for you.  ;)

Comment: @Lou - This partially works, in that it hides the nav, but it is disabling the `nav-sub-wrapper` from displaying when clicking on the hamburger div now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with css itself by using a media query.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .nav-sub-wrapper {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

---

You can also use bootstrap classes to hide/show content on certain screen sizes

The following class will only be visible on a device where the screen width is smaller then 768px.

```
visible-xs-block
```

Here's the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use media queries for the display.  If the hamburger is only visible when at the right size, then you don't even need the other.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hamburger").on('click', function() {
    $(".nav-sub-wrapper").toggle();
  });
})
```

```css
.nav-sub-wrapper {
  display: none;
}

.hamburger {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-sub-wrapper">
  here</div>
<input type=button value=hamburger class="hamburger" />
```